# Means in R: How to find this when the exact list is not known

Tags: r, arithmetic

This is a simple question, not really related to coding but more so to some math that I am missing in my brain.

I know:

An object A has a length of 5 and a mean of 4.
An object B has a length of 10 and a mean of 7.
I make a new object, C, where C <- c(A, 1, B).

What is the mean of C?

Comment: What is the meaning of c(A, 1, B)? is it a combined sequence of A and B?

Comment: A and B are a mystery list of numbers (I don't know the list, only their length and their means).

c(A, 1, B) is a new list which is the list A, the number 1, and the list B (all in one big list, called C).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with R except for the `c(A,1,B)` syntax for concatenation, but:

- sum(A) = 20
- sum(B) = 70
- sum(c(A,1,B)) = 20+70+1 = 91
- length(c(A,1,B)) = 5+10+1 = 16
- mean(c(A,1,B)) = 91/16

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to treat the lists as having their mean value for each component, the correct values are not needed:

```
A = (4, .., 4), 5x
B = (7, .., 7), 10x
1 = (1), 1x
```

and then calculate the new mean:

```
C = (5x4 + 1x1 + 10x7) / (5 + 1 + 10) = 91 / 16
```

It works for arithmetic means:

```
m(A) = (sum A) / |A|
```

The mean of a combined list (A;B) is

```
m((A;B)) = (sum (A;B)) / |(A;B)| = (sum A + sum B) / (|A| + |B|)
```

And the sum of a same length list of mean components is the sum of exact components

```
sum (m(A)) = |A| m(A) = sum A
```